# Sending Custom Fields from Logstash-Forwarder(Lumberjack) to Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

How do I add a custom field in my logstash-forwarder configuration file,such that it can be accessed by logstash?

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if that clears your doubt?

Answer (score 5):

As documented in [README.md](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder/blob/master/README.md), the "files" array in the configuration file contains not only a "paths" array but also a "fields" hash where you can specify additional fields to add to each message coming from the specified files. Example:

```
{
  "network": { ... },
  "files": [
    "paths": [
      "/var/log/syslog"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "type": "syslog"
    }
  ]
}
```